# Fiddle code to .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have working fiddle code having .css and Javascript code and trying to bind both Javascript and CSS into .js file. I am not able to figure out how can I add my HTML and CSS code in .js file.
Can someone help me in binding my code into .js file
please?

```js
(function () {

    var markup =
        '<div class="box note background-gray">' +
        '<div class="box-header">' +
        '<a href="#" class="left add hidden">&plus;</a>' +
        '<a href="#" class="right remove hidden">&times;</a>' +
        '</div><textarea class="note-text"></textarea></div>';

    var spawn = function () {
        $("body").append(makeNote($(markup)));
    };

    var remove = function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    };

    var resizeTextArea = function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var spaceToGrab = 60;
        self.find('.note-text').height(self.height() - 45);
    };

    var hideButtons = function (element) {
        $(element).find("a").hide();
    };

    var showButtons = function (element) {
        $(element).find("a").show();
    };

    var save = function (id, value, position) {
        console.log(id); // position
        console.log(value);
        console.log(position);
    };

    var makeNote = function (element) {
        var $note = $(element);
        $note.resizable({
            handles: "se"
        });
        $note.draggable({
            handle: ".box-header"
        });

        $text = $note.find('textarea');
        $text.focusout(function (e) {
            save($(this).oid, $(this).val(), $(this).parent().position());
        });
        $note.click(function () {
            $(this).find('textarea').focus();
        });

        $note.mouseover(function () {
            showButtons(this);
        });
        $note.mouseout(function () {
            hideButtons(this);
        });

        $note.find(".add").click(spawn);
        $note.find(".remove").click(remove);
        $note.resize(resizeTextArea);
        hideButtons($note);
        return $note;
    };

    $(".note").each(function (i, e) {
        makeNote(e);
    });

    spawn();
})();
```

```css
.box {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}

.note {
    /* box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset; */

    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #888;
    background-color: lime;
}

.box-header {
    min-height: 30px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.box-header a {
    display: block;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;

    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue LT", "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;

    border-radius: 5px;
}

.box-header a:link, .box-header a:visited {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.box-header a:hover, .box-header a:active {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.note-text {
    margin: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    font-style: italic;
    resize: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.background-gray {
    background: #ffffff;

    /* Old browsers */

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* FF3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #e0e0e0));

    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* IE10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e0e0e0', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js" ></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you cannot add css file in .js file, You should create .css file separately to add css and similarly create .js file to add javascript file.

Name your css file as style.css and js file as script.js, I have places js and css in resource folder so that i have given path as below You change accordingly.

```js
(function () {

    var markup =
        '<div class="box note background-gray">' +
        '<div class="box-header">' +
        '<a href="#" class="left add hidden">&plus;</a>' +
        '<a href="#" class="right remove hidden">&times;</a>' +
        '</div><textarea class="note-text"></textarea></div>';

    var spawn = function () {
        $("body").append(makeNote($(markup)));
    };

    var remove = function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    };

    var resizeTextArea = function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var spaceToGrab = 60;
        self.find('.note-text').height(self.height() - 45);
    };

    var hideButtons = function (element) {
        $(element).find("a").hide();
    };

    var showButtons = function (element) {
        $(element).find("a").show();
    };

    var save = function (id, value, position) {
        console.log(id); // position
        console.log(value);
        console.log(position);
    };

    var makeNote = function (element) {
        var $note = $(element);
        $note.resizable({
            handles: "se"
        });
        $note.draggable({
            handle: ".box-header"
        });

        $text = $note.find('textarea');
        $text.focusout(function (e) {
            save($(this).oid, $(this).val(), $(this).parent().position());
        });
        $note.click(function () {
            $(this).find('textarea').focus();
        });

        $note.mouseover(function () {
            showButtons(this);
        });
        $note.mouseout(function () {
            hideButtons(this);
        });

        $note.find(".add").click(spawn);
        $note.find(".remove").click(remove);
        $note.resize(resizeTextArea);
        hideButtons($note);
        return $note;
    };

    $(".note").each(function (i, e) {
        makeNote(e);
    });

    spawn();
})();
```

```css
.box {

    min-width: 100px;

    min-height: 100px;

    margin: 20px;

    display: block;

    width: 200px;

}

.note {

    /* box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset; */

    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #888;

    background-color: lime;

}

.box-header {

    min-height: 30px;

    background-color: #e0e0e0;

    text-align: right;

    line-height: 30px;

}

.box-header a {

    display: block;

    margin: 4px;

    width: 20px;

    height: 20px;

    line-height: 20px;

    font-size: 24px;

    text-align: center;

    font-weight: bolder;

    font-family:"Helvetica Neue LT", "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";

    text-decoration: none;

    color: #666;

    border-radius: 5px;

}

.box-header a:link, .box-header a:visited {

    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;

}

.box-header a:hover, .box-header a:active {

    border: 1px solid #aaa;

    background-color: #ccc;

}

.left {

    float: left;

}

.right {

    float: right;

}

.hidden {

    display: none;

}

.note-text {

    margin: 0;

    background: none;

    border: none;

    font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";

    font-size: 24px;

    width: 100%;

    font-style: italic;

    resize: none;

    overflow: auto;

    outline: none;

    padding: 5px;

}

.background-gray {

    background: #ffffff;

    /* Old browsers */

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* FF3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #e0e0e0));

    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* IE10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e0e0e0', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js" ></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<%@include file="/resources/js/script.js" %>
</script>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css"
 rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
<body>
Your body goes here  
</body>
</html>
```